# How to transfer entire s3 Bucket to Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[Lifecycle Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbKNr.png)I'm still a bit new to aws and s3. I have a s3 bucket that contains around 2.2 TB and I need to move all of it to glacier. I created a policy (I think) that moves it to glacier and told to delete things that were older than 7 days yet I still see all the files. When I click on glacier in the console I see my vault with no files in it. I'm really confused on what I did wrong or if I'm even doing this right at all!! Any advice would be great!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you share your policy settings. The best way how to describe your bucket policy is to use `aws cli`, but also screenshots can be sufficient. We use Glacier as archive storage for some data, which are yearly manually uploaded to S3 to standard tier. We created bucket policy, which moves this data after 1 day to Glacier. There is no need to delete them from S3 once they are moved to the Glacier, because each object have only one storage class specified at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an item to S3 and transition to Glacier, you can only access the item from the S3 console. Additionally, transitioning is not instant and can take several hours. Once your object has been transitioned, the `Storage Class` column will indicate what storage class it is in.

You can refer to the [Transitioning objects using Amazon S3 Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html#before-deciding-to-archive-objects) documentation for more details about the process of transitioning S3 objects.

Comment: so once they are in glacier are they out of s3?? I don't want to be billed for both

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on glacier in the console I see my vault with no files in it.

I think you are confusing [Amazon S3 Glacier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/introduction.html) with [S3 storage class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-glacier) is S3.

In both cases, **S3 glacier backed** is used. But S3 storage class as available in **S3 console** is a user friendly tool to allow people to easily store their objects in S3 Glacier. This is all done through S3 console and the details of integration of working with S3 Glacier are hidden from you.

You can also work **directly with S3 Glacier**, using dedicated **S3 Glacier console**. However, this is not straight forward. Working with Glacier directly is challenging. For example:

- you can't use your object names. glacier will use some random names.
- no direct support for multi-uploads.
- no support for upload of your files through glacier console - only CLI or SDK.

Thus, it much easier when you are using S3 console to work with glacier. But your objects uploaded using S3 console **will not appear** in any vaults in S3 Glacier console. In both cases its the same backed (glacier) but different management fronted.

Since you've created **lifecycle policy** to move objects to S3, you have to use S3 console to interact with your glacier archive. They won't be visible in S3 Glacier console.

Comment: so once they are in glacier are they out of s3?? I don't want to be billed for both

Comment: @alpine1927 They will be stored in glacier storage class. So you won't be paying for standard storage class. Only for glacier.

Comment: Here is a link to what I'm being charged why don't I see Glacier? https://imgur.com/a/PETiKSI